# Positive SSL trusted in Chrome for desktop but not for Android

Tags: android, apache, google-chrome, ssl

I have just bought a Positive SSL Certificate but it does not work in Chrome for Android, I get `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. However, everything is OK with the Chrome for desktop.

This is how I configure my **apache2** server:

```
# File /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ServerName example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /root/ssl/certificate/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile  /root/ssl/example.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /root/ssl/certificate/intermediates.crt
        # In version 2.4.8 or newer
        #SSLCACertificateFile /root/ssl/certificate/intermediates.crt

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And here it's how I created `intermediates.crt`:

```
cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt > intermediates.crt
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Impossible to say without the URL or the actual contents of the *.crt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying almost every combination, I found the **solution**. I had to create the bundle using all the files: my certificate, the two intermediates and the root.

```
cat example.com.crt \
    COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt \
    COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt \
    AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > intermediates.crt
```

Comment: According to the Apache documentation, `SSLCertificateChainFile` is not meant to include the server certificate, though apparently [it can](http://serverfault.com/a/382638). If you have Apache 2.4.8 or later, you can use the concatenated file with `SSLCertificateFile` directly, skipping `SSLCertificateChainFile`. In any case, you [do not need to include the root certificate](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/65333). I'm not sure what ultimately fixed this for you, but the [SSL Labs Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) can help identify issues with the certificate chain.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the intermediates were wrong, but taking a closer look at the Comodo website, your configuration appears to be correct -- the right certificates in the right order.

Have you tried running your site through the [SSL Labs Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)?